# How to have a button that sends more than one value back to the ActionResult with jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, actionresult

I have this button with which I want to send data back to the ActioResult. I want to send and id and an entity name. The id works fine, but when I also want to send the entity name it does not work. How do I send back multiple variables to the ActionResult? This is my html/javascript:

```
@model test.Web.Framework.Areas.Administration.Models.TabNotesModel 
@using (UI.DocumentReadyScript())
{
    if (Model.meta.id.HasValue)
    {
        UI.jQuery("#tbl" + Model.meta.modelname).flexigrid(Model.Grid);
        }
    }
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("TabNotes", new { cmd = "refresh" })"  id="@Model.meta.modelname">
<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all highlight" data-bind="visible: meta.message">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span><strong data-bind="text: meta.message">
    </strong>
</div>
@using (UI.BeginBlock("Administation.TabNotes", UI.Label("Notes", "Notes").ToString(), test.Web.Framework.Core.enumIcons.pencil, false, false))
{
    <table id="@("tbl" + Model.meta.modelname)">
    </table>
}
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    $('#load-partial').click(function() {
        $('#partial').load('@Url.Action("CreateNote", "Entity", new {itemId = @Model.meta.id, modelEntity = @Model.meta.entity})');
// I also tried modelEntity = "Phrase" to test, but that also didn't work
        }); 
    })(); 
</script>

<div id="partial"></div>
<button type="button" id="load-partial">Create Note</button>
```

and my ActionResult. The modelEntity stays null. The itemId does get the number.

```
   public ActionResult CreateNote(
        [ModelBinder(typeof(Models.JsonModelBinder))]
        NoteModel Model, string cmd, long? itemId, string modelEntity)
    {

        if (cmd == "Save")
        {
            Model.meta.message = "Note saved";
            Entity entity = NotesRepository.GetEntity(modelEntity);
            NotesRepository.StoreNote(Model.subject, Model.text, entity, itemId);
            return RedirectToAction("TabNotes", new { modelEntity = modelEntity, id = itemId});
        }

        Model.meta.modelname = "CreateNote";
        Model.meta.JsViewModelType = "EditNoteModel";
        Model.meta.PostAction = Url.Action("CreateNote", new { cmd = "Save", itemId = itemId, modelEntity = modelEntity});


        return PartialView("CreateNotePartial",Model);

        }
```

Comment: Do you have a route configured, containing a modelEntity placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url.Action only takes route values there, so you I think you need a route to cope with the second parameter. I assume your current route already has itemId which is why it works.

Comment: How can I make a route for a new variable?

Comment: In Global.asax you should see your routes, you should have one that looks like `{controller}/{action}/{itemId}` - you need to add another optional parameter to this so it looks like `{controller}/{action}/{itemId}/{modelEntity}` that way the controller `Entity/CreateNote` will get two parameters.

Comment: My Global.asax only has <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="test.Web.Healthcare.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: I can't find it, and there is no {controller}/{action}/{itemId} in the whole solution. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I found global.asax.cs but there is no {controller}/{action}/{itemId} in it.

Comment: So itemId is passed as a querystring? `Entity/CreateNote?itemId=123&modelEntity=YYY` rather than the MVC 'nice' URL type of `Entity/CreateNote/123/YYY`

Comment: Do you have Fiddler? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ will let you see what exactly is being sent by the browser/ajax. It's very easy and free to use. I can't see a problem with the code really.

Comment: Yes it is, fiddler shows me http://localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/CreateNote?itemId=44&amp;modelEntity=Phrase, so it does have modelEntity in there

Comment: So the problem lies in the CreateNote method somewhere -  I would try stripping it down to just itemId and modelEntity as the only two parameters and build up from there (or create a method CreateNoteAjax for testing).